# populate dropdown onload by passing php array to javascript function

Tags: javascript, php, json

im trying to pass a php array to javascript function onload that will display the js array in a drop down list but now im already doing it for sometime i guess i need to pop it again

first i pass it from one php file to another using this code

```
header("location: Rules.php?varFields=".serialize($varFields));
```

secondly i transfer to another variable as it had been passed to the said php file

```
<?php
$varArray = unserialize($_GET['varFields']);
?>
```

third part is im tyring to pass it into a jS functon that will then display it to a drop down list

```
<body id="body"  onclick="cmbRuleField(\'' + <?php echo json_encode($varArray);?> + '\');"    >
```

and here is the external javascript code

```
function cmbRuleField(varArray)//ruleField 
{   
    var varDisplay = JSON.stringify(varArray);

        var sel = document.getElementById("ruleField") // find the drop down

        for (var i in varDisplay) 
        { // loop through all elements

            var opt = document.createElement("option"); // Create the new element
            opt.value = varDisplay [i]; // set the value
            opt.text = varDisplay [i]; // set the text
            sel.appendChild(opt); // add it to the select
        }

}
```

for the first two part i already tested it and it is working but for the last parts i cant make it work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this part looks suspicious

```
<body id="body"  onclick="cmbRuleField(\'' + <?php echo json_encode($varArray);?> + '\');"    >
```

maybe

```
<body id="body"  onclick="cmbRuleField(<?php echo json_encode($varArray);?>)">
```

is more like it.

One more tip, you can see the output on the rendered page to determine what the written out code looks like. So if you see something like:

```
<body id="body"  onclick="cmbRuleField('['a', 'b']')">
```

you know there is a problem. You want a native Javascript array to be passed like this

```
<body id="body"  onclick="cmbRuleField(['a', 'b'])">
```

**EDIT**

After talking on chat it became clear the top portion of OP's code needed a tweak as well.

```
header("location: Rules.php?varFields=".http_build_query($varFields));
```

Comment: Just use the second line from my example bro. You are trying to put single quotes around the array so it's not getting passed to `cmbRuleField` as an array, you see what I mean?

Comment: Also, take a look at the code in the browser, like I suggested in my update and you will see what I mean. You need to pass an array to `cmbRuleField`, not a string.

Comment: okay i will try it and get back to you thanks bro just a moment

Comment: varFields=a:6:{i:0;s:6:"ruleId";i:1;s:9:"ruleNames";i:2;s:11:"checkFields";i:3;s:15:"checkParameters";i:4;s:5:"recom";i:5;s:8:"logTypes";}                     take a look at this it is passing an array

Comment: You're passing it a `serialize`d php array instead of a `json_encode`d array! Take a closer look. You want to pass a Javascript array.

Comment: yup bro sorry for that i already checked, i still cannot figured it out try every solution that I know.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48107/discussion-between-quickshiftin-and-user3287181)

Comment: Click on the link for the chat. I'm in there now, ready to help out.

Comment: Right here: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48107/discussion-between-quickshiftin-and-user3287181

Comment: if you are still there can you correct this code bro thanks 
header("location: Rules.php?varFields=".json_encode($varFields));
$varArray = json_decode($_GET['varFields']);
onload="cmbRuleField(<?php echo json_encode($varArray);?>);
var varDisplay = (JSON.parse(arrayyy));

Comment: You're still using `json_encode` on the URL piece. It should be `http_build_query`. `header("location: Rules.php?varFields=".http_build_query($varFields));`

Answer (score 1):

The problem has to do with quotes not being terminated here:

```
...
<body id="body"  onclick="cmbRuleField(\'' + <?php echo json_encode($varArray);?> + '\');"    >
...
```

The JSON created using json_encode will have a lot of double quotes. Try this:

```
<script>
var array = <?php echo json_encode($varArray);?>;
</script>
<body id="body" onclick="cmbRuleField(array);">
```

Comment: then when it is already in the jS function i just have to use the array as is bro?

Comment: ill get back to you wait

Comment: Any errors come up in the console? Can you post your code?

Comment: nothing show ups bro, the drop down just does not show anything

Answer (score 1):

There is a much easier way. Encode the $varArray as direct HTML options before sending to the browser. For instance:

```
<select id="ruleField">
<?php for ($i = 0; $i < count($varArray); $i++) { ?>
        <option value="<?php= $varArray[$i].val ?>"><?php= $varArray[$i].name ?></option>
<?php } ?>       
</select>
```

Comment: That looks painful! `json_encode` is probably the right direction.

Comment: Or even better, make a dedicated php function to take any array and return a list of options. You will probably use that a lot. Then you can do thinks like `<select id="ruleField"><?php= optionsFor($varArray) ?></select>

Comment: @quickshiftin: painful? Sending an array as a JSON string to the browser and then using browser-specific code to build html elements on the fly is not painful? The user is already building the rest of the page (forms, select fields etc) in php. 3 lines of additional PHP vs. hours of debugging javascript sounds anything but painful.

Comment: Yes painful. There's no need to build out a ton of extra markup when you can send an array directly as OP is trying to do. Hours of debugging, that's hilarious bro, keep the jokes coming!

Answer (score 0):

Might be because you are calling JSON.stringify on something that is already a string?

Also what is myCars?

```
..
for (var i in myCars)
..
```

Possibly rename it to varArray.

or rename varDisplay to varArray.

and lastly try calling JSON.parse instead:

```
function cmbRuleField(varArray)//ruleField 
{   
    var varDisplay = JSON.parse(varArray);

        var sel = document.getElementById("ruleField") // find the drop down

        for (var i in myCars) 
        { // loop through all elements

            var opt = document.createElement("option"); // Create the new element
            opt.value = varDisplay [i]; // set the value
            opt.text = varDisplay [i]; // set the text
            sel.appendChild(opt); // add it to the select
        }

}
```

If that didn't work post the html output here so peeps can create a fiddle :)

Comment: i already tried doing that one bro by the way I already change myCars to varDisplay, incase you will notice, any other idea bro? and i dont have any html error or stuffs it just does not show anything in my drop down list bro.